# How to scroll horizontally GridView programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

`RecycleView` can be scrolled with `smoothScrollBy` method. But Gridview is not extending `RecycleView`. How can I scroll `GridView` like the way RecycleView?

Tried with `gridView.smoothScrollBy(0, dy);` but it does not has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `smoothScrollByOffset(int offset)`.
Offset - The amount to offset from the adapter position to scroll to.
You can also use `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`.

Comment: I do not know the position difference need to scroll, it can be a float value sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you're looking for is [scrollListBy(int y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#scrollListBy(int)) from the AbsListView:

> Scrolls the list items within the view by a specified number of
> pixels.

You could also use [smoothScrollBy(int y, int duration)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int)) for a smooth scroll.